# I can not make the variable "v" receive any characters while the variable "k" receives only alphanumeric

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Could someone help me with this?

I can not make the variable "v" receive any characters while the variable "k" receives only alphanumeric.

```
t = {}     
for k, v in string.gmatch(decrypt, "(%w+)=([^']*)") do
  t[k] = v
print(k,v)
end
```

I have a file with the following content:

```
email=mbw@iue.com
ip=192.168.100.1
mac=af:45:t6:45:67
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(maybe oversimplifying, if so, sorry...)
If you are trying to break the lines in your file at the '=' an assign them as key, value pairs in t:

```
--
-- PART I - read from a file
--
local file = "pattern.dat"                     -- our data file
local t = {}                                   -- hold file values
for l in io.lines(file) do                     -- get one line at a time
    local k, v = string.match(l, "(.+)=(.+)")  -- key, value delimited by '=''
    t[k] = v                                   -- save in table
    print(k,t[k])
end

print("\n\n")

--
-- PART II - read from data string
--
local data = "email=mbw@iue.com/ip=192.168.100.1/mac=af:45:t6:45:67"
data = data .. "/"                              -- need a trailing '/'
t = {}                                          -- hold data values
for l in string.gmatch(data, "(.-)/") do        -- get one 'line' at a time
    local k,v = string.match(l, "(.+)=(.+)")    -- key, value delimited by '=''
    t[k] = v
    print(k,t[k])
end
```

NOTE about the "^" anchor (from reference manual entry for 'gmatch'):

> For this function, a caret '^' at the start of a pattern does not work as an anchor, as this would prevent the iteration.
>   http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch

Comment: Hello, you helped me a lot! your code works perfectly, Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi JLP Labs,
On another occasion I will need to get this data otherwise example:

data = "email=commercial@eia.com/id=13412513251315/mac=12:A4: 67:89:fg/ip = 192.168.1.100"

Instead of file, the data is in a single line could tell me how to get the same result of your code above?

Comment: Once again thank my friend, you helped me very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are actually only getting one match because `*` is greedy. If you are trying to split lines, try `(%w+)=([^'\n]*)\n`

Note: Lua uses patterns, not regular expressions. Sometimes the difference is unimportant, sometimes vital.

Comment: Thanks for your attention!